# Static File configuration Amazon S3

Tags: django

I followed the below url to move my static files to Amazon S3.

http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/2012/07/14/using-amazon-s3-to-host-your-django-static-files/

and here is my static configuration in settings.py

```
    if not DEBUG:
        INSTALLED_APPS += ('storages',)
        AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['mybucket']
        STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
        STATIC_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/'%AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    else:
        STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATIC_ROOT = ''

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets',os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '../static')),
)
```

after this when I try

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

I get the following message

```
Unknown command: 'collectstatic'
```

what could be the issue. I haven't set the Aws Access Key., Secret Key anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Add the staticfiles app to the installed apps.

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

The `collectstatic` is managed by the above app.

Comment: I dont think that is the issue., It is working if DEBUG is True.

Comment: debug = true does not use the static files app.if debug = true static files are managed by django itself which is not recommended.static must be handled by the web server itself.

Comment: Yes. But I want to move the static files to Amazon S3 in this case Webserver need not handle it right ? How to move the files to Amazon S3.

Comment: i am not familiar with the amazon s3 config,however,when i host my apps in heroku i deploy the code in heroku and my static files in some other free php hosting.